# Complex split regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

## Problem

I'm having trouble with a regular expression.

I have a set of strings.

#### Example String

```
@param* URL url './' an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
@param* Function callback callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) The function that will be executed on every object.
@param Function callback Null The function that will be executed when the image is clicked
@param String name 'this is a test name' the name to use when displaying the image
@param String name "this is a test name" the name to use when displaying the image
```

I'm splitting them on the new line to give me individual string.

```
var match = val.split("\n");
```

Each of these strings can be broken down into five values:

#### Variables

Example: `@param Function callback Null The function that will be executed when the image is clicked`

```
@param = required;
Function = type;
callback = name;
Null = default;
The function that will be executed when the image is clicked = description.
```

What I need is to break this string up into its parts taking into account all the different string possibilities, i'm having a hard time creating the regular expression that can split on all the different default and description posibilites.

I'm having a particular problems trying to get the defaultValue out when its a string in double or single quotes or when it's in function notation.

## Code

This is my current working code;

```
$.each(match, function(index, value) {
    var part = value.split(/\s/); //TODO need a regx to split this string correctly

    var required     = part[0];
    var type         = part[1];
    var name         = part[2];
    var defaultValue = part[3];
    var description  = part[4];
});
```

## Summary

I need a single or multiple step regular expression that can break up all five examples above into the same five variables.

Edit: I apologies for not having had a go at the regular expression but i'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Will the first part always start with `@`?  Also, can any of the first 3 parts be more than one word?

Comment: Yes first part always start with @ and the first three values will always be a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var regExp = /^(@.+?)\s(.+?)\s(.+?)\s(\'.+?\'|\".+?\"|\w.+?\)|\w+?)\s(.*)$/;
results = regExp.exec(value);

var required     = results[0];
var type         = results[1];
var name         = results[2];
var defaultValue = results[3];
var description  = results[4];
```

I tested quickly using http://regexhero.net/tester/ but other than that I didn't test it.

Comment: +1 I had to change the results array to start with one but this seems to work well, I made a little test http://jsfiddle.net/leviputna/J28ms/ and you can see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

This does not use any regex, but I think it is a little easier to understand and maintain.  Also, I'm sure there is slightly more elegant way to perform the if statement, but it is what came to mine on the spur of the moment. http://jsfiddle.net/CcAus/

```
$.each(match, function(index, value) {
    var part = value.split(' ');

    var required     = part.shift();
    var type         = part.shift();
    var name         = part.shift();
    if(part[0][0]=='\''||part[0][0]=='"'){
      part = part.join(' ');
      var defaultValue = part.split(part[0][0]+' ',1)+part[0][0];
      part=part.replace(defaultValue,'')
      var description = part;
    }
    else{
      var defaultValue = part.shift();
      var description = part.join(' ');
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 - the only thing this doesn't do is escaped quotes in the default value, which is not necessarily a problem here.

Comment: Thanks, this works great except when the default value is a function callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) http://jsfiddle.net/leviputna/h5vB4/1/ i'm trying to find a fix.